# How to add div and multiple images in it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a div in a page and then add multiple images to it using jQuery, i have found some method [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and try to implement it but image is not appearing although div is inserted in the body.

I am trying to do it like this.

```
        $(window).load(function(){

        $("<div/>", {
          "id": "image",
          "css": { "display" : "block"},
        }).appendTo("body");

        $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout.png'/>").appendTo("#image");
        $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout2.png'/>").appendTo("#image");

        });
```

Please see whats the best approach to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: You should cross check your images path.

Comment: sorry my bad it was the images path problem, thanks for mentioning it, got it right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div/>", {
  "id": "image",
  "css": {"display" : "block"},
  html: $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout.png'/>
           <img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout2.png'/>")
}).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
$('#image').prepend('<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/layout.png'/>')
```

or

```
$('<img />')
    .attr('src', '_ls-global/layout-images/layout.png')
    .appendTo('#image'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try do the following (and make sure your image path is correct):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var imageContainer = $('<div id="imageDiv"></div>');
var image1 = $('<img src="_ls-global/layout-images/layout.png" style="display:block"/>');
var image2 = $('<img src="_ls-global/layout-images/layout2.png" style="display:block"/>');
imageContainer.append(image1);
imageContainer.append(image2);
$('body').append(imageContainer);
});
```